# What is the correct syntax to enable fullscreen toggle in Pygame?

Tags: python, user-interface, pygame

I have looked at the documentation but I can't seem to implement the full screen toggle. Could someone please show me an example of the correct syntax?

Comment: tried [this](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/toggle_fullscreen)?

Comment: It should be `screen=pygame.display.set_mode((x, y), pygame.FULLSCREEN)`

Answer (score 1):

Your can use the following code snippet.

```
size=(640,480)
....
#init your pygame
pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode(size, DOUBLEBUF)
flags=screen.get_flags()   
...
#events in your pygame app
event1 = pygame.event.poll()
if event1.type == KEYDOWN:
    if event1.key == K_ESCAPE:
        break    
    elif event1.key ==K_f:
        #toggle fullscreen by pressing F key.
        if flags&FULLSCREEN==False:
            flags|=FULLSCREEN
            pygame.display.set_mode(size, flags)
        else:
            flags^=FULLSCREEN
            pygame.display.set_mode(size, flags)
```

Answer (score 0):

`pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen()`  use this function